# Can't use two .replace() for one element

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code to capitalize the first letter input into a text box and I have another code to disallow numbers to be input into the same text box.
The problem is, if I use one, the other doesn't work and I was hoping someone could tell me how to combine both of them with one `.replace()`
I use the following code to capitalize the first letter input:

```
$(this).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }));
```

And I use this code to disallow numbers in my text box:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,''));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try chaining the two calls to `replace()`?

Comment: Offtopic: You can simplify your regexp for capitalization to `/\b[a-z]/gi`. `\b` means a word boundary, so it will match the beginning of the string or right before a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the code into two function which each accept a string and return a string. Now you can combine the two in any order:

```
$(this).val(disallowNumbers(capitalize($(this).val())));
```

**[EXIT]** I fixed the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DnMN3/1/

The original code had a problem: By allowing only lower case letters in the "disallow numbers" check, the capitalized letters were swallowed. So the code replaced `a` with `A` which was then no longer allowed.

Comment: Nice solution, but should probably be in the other order. So it will capitalize the word after removing any disallowed numbers at the beginning.

Comment: @surfsup: Can you provide a fiddle that doesn't work so i can fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just nudge the two together? I don't see what the problem is?

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'').replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }));
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: When I use this code, I can't input more than one character and I can't input capital letters.